# Elasticsearch sort result by non mandatory fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets imagine that we have the following documents:

```
 [{
    "translations": {
      "0": "3 Trunk.",
      "4": "1 Trunk. 3"
    },
    "defaultValue": "3 Trunk."
  },
  {
    "translations": {
      "0": "3 Trunk.",
      "4": "DDDDD"
    },
    "defaultValue": "3 Trunk."
  },
  {
    "translations": {
      "0": "3 Trunk."
    },
    "defaultValue": "3 Trunk."
  }]
```

And we try to sort:

```
 "sort": [
        {
            "translations.4.sortword": {
                "unmapped_type": "keyword",
                "missing": "_last",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        },
        {
            "translations.0.sortword": {
                "unmapped_type": "keyword",
                "missing": "_last",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
```

In UI we use translated value or default([0]) so we will see

**1 Trunk. 3**

**DDDDD**

**3 Trunk.**

How I can sort it in the correct way? Is there some projection/aggregation like in mongo which can help to do this?

Comment: So, you want the sorted result like: `1 Trunk. 3` -> `3 Trunk.` -> `DDDDD` right?

Comment: @occidere yes. **1 Trunk. 3** and **DDDDD** will be sorted by **translations.4**. **3 Trunk.** will be sorted by translations.0 because it hasn't translations.4

Comment: i want that they are sorted in this way... but how to do it idk